Trying to automate URL inspection in google but cannot get past authentication
Google isn't clear to me on how I can login to the google search console API.
I'm using PHP and CURL.
I passed in for the URL: "sites/example.com/searchAnalytics/query?key=mykey" and I passed in json parameters for the start and end date. mykey was assigned to me after using google cloud to generate one.
When I execute the curl request through PHP, I receive this error:
"API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal."
Oauth2 wouldn't be for me because I'm using an private apache server on my computer to handle the requests.
So I looked into google cloud and I'm able to get a unique ID, a client ID and an email ending in iam.gserviceaccount.com
What values do I feed into CURL when making an authenticated request? I would assume I'd place them in as an HTTP header but google is not clear on this.
Please help.
I tried the API key but the google search API wouldn't allow that as authentication.

"Oauth2 wouldn't be for me"...think again. use a Service Account: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

"What values do I feed into CURL" ...why DIY? https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

3rd party package add alot of unnecessary code that I have to cut down to get the information I need.

I believe I have made a service account with google cloud but I don't know how to apply the credentials to a curl request.

It tells you in the "Preparing to make a delegated call" and "Calling Google APIs" sections of the documentation, if you change the tab to "HTTP/REST". As you can see, submitting the credentials and getting the access token is relatively complex - which is why I said not to make a do-it-yourself solution using cURL. Instead use Google's API client for PHP, at which point it becomes a lot easier. Everything you need to do this task is already available in the documentation.

As well as the example in the last link I gave you, there's also a full worked example of authentication and making a request via a service account using the PHP library here
